# Get df cell value based on user-selection in Streamlit

Tags: pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have a Streamlit app that allows the user to make a selection from reward_options.df. After selection, I would like to display the value in column 2 of the dataframe associated with that item from column 1. I do not have these items indexed.
I attempted to use the .loc method but this isn't working, I get a Key Error in Streamlit. Any suggestions?

==

selected_reward = st.selectbox(
"Choose a reward",
reward_options_df,0)

selected_reward_price = reward_options_df.loc[selected_reward,"Price (Coins)"]

==

[reward_options_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUbS9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Her is one approach.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['Bagel', 'Coffee', 'Smart TV'], 'Price (Coins)': [125, 110, 7000]})

st.table(df)

selected_reward = st.selectbox("Choose a reward", df.Item, 0)

selected_reward_price = df.loc[df.Item == selected_reward]["Price (Coins)"].iloc[0]

st.write(f'Price: {selected_reward_price}')
```

#### Output

[image]